# Magento 2 : Add Custom Tax Amount In Cart Programatically

Tags: magento2, cart, tax, totals

I want to add custom tax amount to checkout cart programmatically.

Here is the example.

```
Cart Old Tax = 4.21

Custom Tax = 2

New Tax = 4.21 + 2 = 6
```

Check the screenshot below.

[image]

**I need this done programmatically.**

Comment: Where your `custom amount` come from?

Comment: @ToanNguyen that I fetch from the session, My point is how can add that value to tax.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, below solution i tried,this is showing cart but not calculating..

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - did you get the solution to this problem ?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya, did you get solution for this/

Answer (score 8):

You can observe to the event `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after` and achieve it. For this, you need to setup a module and configure an event. Let's say our module is `MStack_Exchange`.

File : `app\code\MStack\Exchange\etc\events.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after">
        <observer name="changeTaxTotal" instance="MStack\Exchange\Observer\ChangeTaxTotal"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

File : `app\code\MStack\Exchange\Observer\ChangeTaxTotal.php`

```
<?php
namespace MStack\Exchange\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class ChangeTaxTotal implements ObserverInterface
{
    public $additionalTaxAmt = 2;

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total */
        $total = $observer->getData('total');

        //make sure tax value exist
        if (count($total->getAppliedTaxes()) > 0) {
            $total->addTotalAmount('tax', $this->additionalTaxAmt);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The important call here is : `$total->addTotalAmount('tax', $this->additionalTaxAmt);`. This will add `2` with the existing tax amount and I think that is what you need in your case. So what you need to do is, replace `$this->additionalTaxAmt` with your tax buffer value.

The event `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_after` fires just after total calculations had been happend and hence thus become perfect place to play around.

If you are curious to know where this total calculations are happening, then you need to look into `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector::collect()` and `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\TotalsCollector::collectAddressTotals()` methods.

Comment: Let me check this.

Comment: @Rajeev, can we add custom tax for individual product when added to cart? here is my question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Comment: Thanks @Rajeev to save my day

Comment: Hi @rajeev , I want to clear all taxes programmatically before adding custom tax and also want to add title of tax.Can you please let me know how to achieve it?

Comment: @akgola Hi, I am not sure which version you are referring to and feel your question is broad and cannot answer in a comment. Better ask a new question with details in the platform so that the community will help you to accomplish your need

Comment: Hi @RajeevKTomy , I am using 2.3.4 version.Please refer my question and if possible please help me    https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/320658/24878

Comment: But this tax not added into invoice & credit-memo.

Answer (score 3):

@Dhiren Vasoya

Use these lines as well.

```
$total->addBaseTotalAmount('tax', $this->additionalTaxAmt);
$total->setGrandTotal((float)$total->getGrandTotal() + $this->additionalTaxAmt);
$total->setBaseGrandTotal((float)$total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $this->additionalTaxAmt);
```

Comment: this tax is not getting added in invoice section.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a db table to collect Tax for each product item and Applied on Cart page, So it can save into quote table
Create **sales.xml** file in app/code/VENDOR_NAME/MODULE_NAME/etc/sales.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="customtax" instance="VENDOR_NAME/MODULE_NAME\Model\Total\Quote\CustomTax" sort_order="500"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

Now Create a mode file CustomTax.php at **app/code/VENDOR_NAME/MODULE_NAME\Model\Total\Quote\CustomTax.php**

```
    <?php 
    namespace VENDOR_NAME\MODULE_NAME\Model\Total\Quote;
    use Exception;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Session as CustomerSession;
    use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total;
    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal;
    use Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation;
    
    class CustomTax extends AbstractTotal
    {
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
            PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
            Calculation $calculation,
            CustomerSession $customerSession
           
        ) {
            $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
            $this->calculation = $calculation;
            $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
            $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
        }
    
        /**
         * Collect extra fee totals
         *
         * @param Quote $quote
         * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
         * @param Total $total
         *
         * @return $this
         * @throws Exception
         */
        public function collect(
            Quote $quote,
            ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
            Total $total
        ) {
            parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
            $totalTax = $this->getProductInfor($quote);
            $total->setTaxAmount($totalTax); //set tax amount here
            $total->setGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal()+$totalTax); 
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getProductInfor( $quote){
            if($quote->getItemsQty()>=0){
                $items = $quote->getAllItems();
                $taxPercent =0;
                foreach($items as $item){
                    $qty = $item->getQty();
                    $sku = $item->getSku();
                    $select = $this->connection->select()
                    ->from(
                        ['c' => 'custom_product_tax'], //table Name here
                        ['tax']                        //column tax
                    )
                    ->where(
                        "c.sku = :sku"
                    );
                $bind = ['sku'=>$sku];
                $records = $this->connection->fetchAll($select, $bind);
                $tax = $records[0]['tax'];  
                if(!empty($tax)){    
                    $taxPercent += ($tax/100)*$item->getBaseRowTotal();
                }
                }
                return $taxPercent;
            }
        }
    }
```