# how to update tax amount with custom price in magento 2

Tags: magento2, tax

HOW TO UPDATE TAX WITH CUSTOM VALUE IN CART OR CHECKOUT.My requirement was when customer click add to cart and he move to cart that time i want to update tax with some API so do the needful.

Comment: Do you find how to set tax amount? if yes than please post it how to do this?

Comment: I have tried this and working fine https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353374/82482

Answer (score 3):

One approach is :

You can try to overide the default collect total tax function.

**Add this dependency :**

```
<preference for="Magento\Tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Tax\Sales\Total\Quote\Tax"/>
```

**Create you own Quote Tax Collection function based on native one.**

Add your logic inside the collect function.

Example :

```
/**
 * Custom Collect tax totals for quote address
 *
 * @param Quote $quote
 * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
 * @param Address\Total $total
 * @return $this
 * @throws RemoteServiceUnavailableException
 */
public function collect(
    Quote $quote,
    ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    Address\Total $total
) {
    $address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();

    $storeId = $quote->getStoreId();

    if ($this->doNotUseCustomTax()
    ) {
        return parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
    }

    $this->processCustomTax($quote);

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: ok i will try now

Comment: i am new to magento 2 can you please elaborate this answer with detail..because i tried but ..

Comment: I do not have the detail of the implementation sorry, I just share you an approach. Let's wait other answers.

Comment: ok,i am getting tax in my custom module and updated the tax trying to set with  ""$total->setTaxAmount($taxAmount);"" but $total not getting value

Comment: Try to find how this module works : https://github.com/classyllama/ClassyLlama_AvaTax It is used to setup custom taxes for the US.

Comment: @FranckGarnier, how can we set custom tax price when product added to cart, here is my full question,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function collect(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
    
    $this->clearValues($total);
    if (!$shippingAssignment->getItems()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $x= $quote->getItems();
    if (isset($x)) {
        foreach ($x as $item) {
            $g = $item;
            $y = $item->getSku();
            $y = $item->getProductId();
        }
    }
    
    $baseTaxDetails = $this->getQuoteTaxDetails($shippingAssignment, $total, true);
    $taxDetails = $this->getQuoteTaxDetails($shippingAssignment, $total, false);

    //Populate address and items with tax calculation results
    $itemsByType = $this->organizeItemTaxDetailsByType($taxDetails, $baseTaxDetails);
    if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT])) {
        $this->processProductItems($shippingAssignment, $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_PRODUCT], $total);
    }

    if (isset($itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING])) {
        $shippingTaxDetails = $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_ITEM];
        $baseShippingTaxDetails =
            $itemsByType[self::ITEM_TYPE_SHIPPING][self::ITEM_CODE_SHIPPING][self::KEY_BASE_ITEM];
        $this->processShippingTaxInfo($shippingAssignment, $total, $shippingTaxDetails, $baseShippingTaxDetails);
    }

    //Process taxable items that are not product or shipping
    $this->processExtraTaxables($total, $itemsByType);

   $total->setTaxAmount(2000);
   $total->setGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal()+2000);
   
    //Save applied taxes for each item and the quote in aggregation
    $this->processAppliedTaxes($total, $shippingAssignment, $itemsByType);

    if ($this->includeExtraTax()) {
        $total->addTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getExtraTaxAmount());
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount('extra_tax', $total->getBaseExtraTaxAmount());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

The above code works for me.

[image]

Comment: this is recalculated on checkout page and back to original tax.

Comment: it works for me. is there anything else overriding the tax at checkout? Please check.

Comment: How you can calculate tax on rowSubtotal amount ?