# Custom VAT amount on products

Tags: magento-2.1, tax, vat

I have applied VAT to products, However, I would need to be able to overwrite the VAT amount when certain conditions are met From [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/159276/54783) question I was able to remove the tax that is automatically calculated, by using `addTotalAmount` to add the same amount as the VAT but multiplies by -1.

I am unsure how to get the individual product ids to be able to get their cost price.

EDIT:
I was able to get the product ids with:

```
    $quote = $observer->getData('quote');
    $itemsList = $quote->getItemsCollection();

    foreach ($itemsList as $item){
        $item->getProductId();          
    }
```

However, some of the products will also have a custom price set in the backend if an order is added manually. I am unable to get that price at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by getting the quote data with:

```
$quote = $observer->getData('quote');
```

and then get the item collection from the quote

```
$itemsList = $quote->getItemsCollection();
```

Next I went through all the items and got the item product id and price, the `getPrice()` will return whatever amount the price set in the Custom Price box.

```
foreach ($itemsList as $item){
    $item->getProductId();          
    $item->getPrice();
}
```